# Get SPListItem in another format

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I want to get different Rows from an SPListItem. I'll show you my problem with an example.
This code

```
Console.WriteLine(SPItemName["Created By"]);
or
Console.WriteLine(SPItemName["Created By"].ToString);
```

returns "8;UserName" (8 is the User ID).
If I look up the row in SharePoint Designer, i can choose even a format for this data field.
So i could get the html code of this field.

How to set the format (like html code or text) of a datafield in c#?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use Either SPFieldLookupValue

If you need just the username, use `SPFieldLookupValue` to seperate id from value:
`var userValue = new SPFieldLookupValue(SPItemName["Created By"] as string)`

Then you can:

- `userValue.LookupValue` to return UserName
- `userValue.LookupId` to return Id

### Or SPFieldUserValue

Or better yet, you can create SPFieldUserValue object to access any other user properties like email, login name, etc..

```
SPFieldUserValue objUserFieldValue = new SPFieldUserValue(web, SPItemName["Created By"].ToString());
```

Afterwards you can use:

```
objUserFieldValue.User.LoginName;
objUserFieldValue.User.Name;
objUserFieldValue.User.ID;
objUserFieldValue.User.Groups;
objUserFieldValue.User.Roles;
objUserFieldValue.User.Email;
objUserFieldValue.User.Sid;
objUserFieldValue.User.UserToken;
```

http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/04/spfielduservalue-and.html

Note: to create SPFieldUserValue you must pass reference to web, that's because SharePoint has to get additional user information from user information list to construct SPFieldUserValue object.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot.
Furthermore i want to get other self defined fields and i have got the same problem.

I always get stuff like this "ID;#real content".
Is there an general way to solve this problem?

Comment: @Fabian the class SPFieldLookupValue i mentioned solves the problem. That's the expected way to split that value. Because that's the way SharePoint stores that item (for lookup fields). And it's a good thing, because when you want to do a query based on your lookup field, you can either do it by value or by id. :)